# Multiple ways to read a file?

Tags: python, file

I am not sure if there is a difference in the way the file will be read in the two scenarios below on line 2.  The first scenario has a `'r'` in the open command, and the second one does not.  Both output the same result.  Are these just just different ways to achieve the same result?

Scenario 1:

```
def readit(filename, astr):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    return content.count(astr)

print(readit("payroll.txt","Sue"))
```

Scenario 2:

```
def readit(filename, astr):
    infile = open(filename)
    content = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    return content.count(astr)

print(readit("payroll.txt","Sue"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the two code pieces are equivalent.  `'r'` is the default mode for `open`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`
>
> `mode` is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to `'r'` which means open for reading in
>   text mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
infile = open(filename)    # by default it opens as read-only
```

there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `with` to open the file which, among other benefits, auto closes the file. It is also better to count your target string line-by-line rather than reading the entire file into memory:

```
def readit(filename, astr):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        return sum(line.count(astr) for line in infile)
```

Shorter, less memory, more 'Pythonic'

---

On a side note, `line.count(astr)` will count all occurrences of that substring even if part of a larger string. Example:

```
>>> s='she she he she he sheshe hehe'
>>> s.count('she')
5
>>> s.count('he')
9
```

Consider either splitting the text for a full match:

```
>>> [word for word in s.split() if word=='she']
['she', 'she', 'she']
>>> [word for word in s.split() if word=='he']
['he', 'he']
```

Or a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bshe\b', s)
['she', 'she', 'she']
>>> re.findall(r'\bhe\b', s)
['he', 'he']
```

Answer (score 0):

from the python doc,it's the same.
but if you wanna increase the readable,it's good to add the 'r' mode :)